# How is a quotient defined in an abelian category?

Tags: category-theory

In CWM Saunder Maclane, exercises $6$ page $202$ states:

> For sub-object $u \leq v$ of an object $a$ in an abelian category, define a "quotient" object $v/$u.

What is the exact definition of $v/u$ in this situation?

Comment: What does the next line or two say? It sounds like it's about to define it.

Comment: I want to prove myself : "if $gf=0$" then $kerg/imf$ is isomorphic to the dual object $coimg/cokerf$, To prove this i need the exact meaning of $v/u$ above .

Answer (score 7):

$v/u$ is the cokernel of the monomorphism $u \to v$ (which exists because of $u \leq v$).

Comment: It is kind of weird that the definition is hidden in an exercise, without solution, because quotients are used all the time in the next section on diagram lemmas. When I read the book for the first time, I already knew the definition, but probably this is not so easy for readers who don't. I assume that Mac Lane actually meant something like "Recall the usual definition of a quotient object".

Comment: $u,v$ are not objects are arrows, so why you write $u \rightarrow v$ ?

Comment: Of course I mean their domains.